# SQL - Select In from Array, and NOT in in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a userform built in VBA where my coworkers can enter multiple values that builds an array and places it into an IN statement, which works great. Problem is I need to also be able to display what values do not exist within the tables.

Example table

```
id | value
1  | value1
2  | value2
4  | value4
```

Then a query that could be generated would be

```
SELECT [id],[value] FROM [tablea] WHERE [id] IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Expected or desirable outcome would be as follows

```
id | value
1  | value1
2  | value2
3  | null
4  | value4
```

I've tried doing it like so;

```
SELECT [id],[value] FROM [tablea] WHERE [id] IN (1,2,3,4) AND [id] NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
```

since both arrays will be the same, this returns 0 of course.

I know I can do this with a union, and define the not in statement within the second union, but I'd like to do this without a union.. Any other thoughts?

This is on Microsoft SQL 2005

I unfortunately only have access to SELECT, since I'm performing queries either via VBA or Tableau. So I cannot create a derived table or have anything to reference other than the select statement.

Comment: If you are building an array and doing this I have a very strong suspicion your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Are you building up a string which includes this array and then executing that against your database? That is the textbook definition of sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree. However,the scripts are only ran behind Active Directory with only select rights, and select users.

Comment: @SeanLange while I am here to learn though, what would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest one of two options. Both of them would be using parameters instead of pass through sql. You could either use a table valued parameter (that would be my first choice) or you could pass the delimited list as a parameter and split that.

Answer (score 4):

You need a `left join` of some sort.  One way would be to construct your query as:

```
select v.id, t.value
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)
     ) v(id) left join
     table t
     on v.id = t.id;
```

Comment: Huh. I didn't know you could use the `values` clause like that. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this is a Table Value Constructor. Very handy for this type of thing. :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

Comment: Indeed. I would have had to recommend generating a "numbers" table to filter on his input set before the outer join. It works here, but imagine if those were string values; I'd be really in trouble.

Comment: Afraid I'm using Server 2005, after trying this for a few minutes lol. Updated OP with that detail.

Comment: @JeffBeagley You know that Sql Server 2005 is less than 5 months from End of Life, right? This could be a good excuse to upgrade.

Comment: Thinking through other possibilities, if I had the ability to create temp tables (which I do not), then I could just create that each time with the values, then left join to that.

Comment: You can use a derived table (sub query) or CTE in Sql Server 2005, along with any of the several methods for generating a numbers table inline.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn believe CTE did the trick, thank you! Going to update with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joel Coehoorn for the tip towards using a CTE

I was able to accomplish this like so;

```
WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as num UNION ALL )

SELECT
    COALESCE(id,num) as col1,
    id as col2
FROM tablea

RIGHT JOIN numbers ON tablea.id = numbers.num
```

This would return

```
col1  |  col2
1     |    1
2     |    2
3     |    NULL
4     |    4
```